# Connection to server while behind the rounter in WinSock2, C++

Tags: c++, routes, winsock, firewall, winsock2

I'm writing a very simple server-client application in C++, using WinSocks.

When I set client's parameters as: `resolveHost ("google.pl")` for server's IP and `80` for port, I receive a html (with GET header).

When I run the server first (with port `10000`) and then client (port `10000` IP `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")` it *seems* to works (I receive something).

But when I change the server's IP in client to `inet_addr("188.246.158.171")` (my IP for now, I don't have static IP, I've checked my actual IP with some website), it for sure **DOES NOT** works.

My computer is behind the router - **can it be the problem?**

If so, can I solve it in the way that **don't requite any configuration to router** (port forwarding etc.). Also, I don't want to make anything router's model-specific, so I intentionally haven't posted the model of my router ;)

**Why I don't want to change configuration?**
Because my application will be for "simple people". And simple people won't try to make configuration, and I won't require them to do so.
Also, many applications (on-line games for example) works fine with my router without any configuration - my application cannot be exception (by the example of other applications on my computer, I know it's possible and common to achieve it).

---

I use Visual Studio 2012, works on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a listening server behind a router, you **must** configure port forwarding rules on the router if you want outside clients to reach the server through the router.  You cannot avoid that.  However, if the router supports uPnP (Universal Plug and Play), your server code can configure port forwarding rules programmably, such as with Microsoft's [`IUPnPNAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366182.aspx) interface. Otherwise, you have to use the router's own configuration software (usually an HTTP interface running on the router itself).

You also have to configure ports/permissions on a local firewall, if installed.  Some firewalls have APIs for that, such as [Microsoft's Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366453.aspx).

Online games and other peer-to-peer apps employ several **NAT Traversal** techniques to get around NATs, firewalls, etc.  Hole Punching, Role Reversal, etc.  Do some searches, information is readily available.